# Image uploaded does not upload image, instead refreshes original file

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, upload

When I am uploading images via my html and I click save to upload the image, something has broken.

What happens is instead of uploading the new image, instead it just refreshed the same image. I can see because in my images folder for avatars, now the exact same file shows as just having been updated, but it is not replaced with the new image, it is still the old image.

So the location and the path and everything seems right since it's sending to the folder except something is wrong because it is not replacing the previous image with the new image, it is only updating the old image with the same old image.

Also, I have a function (not pasted in below code) which is a checkbox to delete the image. However, this doesn't work either.

Please help me solve this issue, it has been very annoying. It is not wordpress or anything, just a PHP file.

Here is my PHP

```
$myAvatar = null;
    if((isset($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])) && (strlen($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'])))
    {
        $myAvatar = $_FILES['avatar'];
    }


// save avatar
    $avatarsource = null;
    if($myAvatar)
    {
        // convert all images to jpg
        $imgInfo = getimagesize($myAvatar['tmp_name']);
        switch($imgInfo[2])
        {
            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG: $avatarsource = imagecreatefromjpeg($myAvatar['tmp_name']);
        break;
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG: $avatarsource = imagecreatefrompng($myAvatar['tmp_name']);
        break;
            default: $avatarsource = null;
        }
    }

    if(($avatarsource))
    {
        ob_start();
        imagejpeg($avatarsource, null, 100);
        $imageData = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        if($avatarsource)
        {
            // save new file
            cache::saveCacheToFile($avatarCachePath . '/origin_avatar.jpg', $imageData);
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div>
    <label for="avatar">Upload Avatar</label>
    <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar">>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submit"/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thats because you are always writing the new file to the same filename i.e. `/origin_avatar.jpg`

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be replacing the old image with the new image with same filename.

Comment: Any solution?    -

Comment: Is this a browser caching issue? Have you tried refreshing the browser cache with a CTRL+F5

Comment: Definitely not a browser issue